# Added JTextField to JFrame is not displaying in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have tried to add a `JTextField` inside a `JFrame`. But it's not displaying in window. I'm using the below code for adding the text field to the frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Auto Completion Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 400);

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String item = ""+i+"item";
            items.add(item);
        }
        JTextField txtInput = new JTextField();
        setupAutoComplete(txtInput, items);
        txtInput.setColumns(30);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(1000,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Methods I'm using for autocomplete text is below:

```
 private static boolean isAdjusting(JComboBox cbInput) {
        if (cbInput.getClientProperty("is_adjusting") instanceof Boolean) {
            return (Boolean) cbInput.getClientProperty("is_adjusting");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void setAdjusting(JComboBox cbInput, boolean adjusting) {
        cbInput.putClientProperty("is_adjusting", adjusting);
    }

    public static void setupAutoComplete(final JTextField txtInput, final ArrayList<String> items) {
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        final JComboBox cbInput = new JComboBox(model) {
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width, 0);
            }
        };
        setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
        for (String item : items) {
            model.addElement(item);
        }
        cbInput.setSelectedItem(null);
        cbInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!isAdjusting(cbInput)) {
                    if (cbInput.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        txtInput.setText(cbInput.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        txtInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                setAdjusting(cbInput, true);
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                    if (cbInput.isPopupVisible()) {
                        e.setKeyCode(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    e.setSource(cbInput);
                    cbInput.dispatchEvent(e);
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        txtInput.setText(cbInput.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
                }
                setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
            }
        });
        txtInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList();
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList();
            }

            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList();
            }

            private void updateList() {
                setAdjusting(cbInput, true);
                model.removeAllElements();
                String input = txtInput.getText();
                if (!input.isEmpty()) {
                    for (String item : items) {
                        if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase())) {
                            model.addElement(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                cbInput.setPopupVisible(model.getSize() > 0);
                setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
            }
        });
        txtInput.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        txtInput.add(cbInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

I'm new to java swing application development. Could you please suggest me any idea to do this?

Comment: pack the frame before making it visible.

Comment: Your code works for me, except that I have commented the `setupAutoComplete` part out. Could you provide the `setupAutoComplete` method ?

Comment: @Berger okay will post it

Comment: 1) *"okay will post it"* **Don't** post uncompilable code snippets. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  2) Swing/AWT GUIs should be started on the EDT.

Comment: @MissingSemiColon i'm getting this error when trying to pack it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method pack() from the type Window"

Comment: This is really wrong : `txtInput.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        txtInput.add(cbInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`, you are changing the Layout Manager of your `JTextField`, and attempting to add a `JComboBox` to it, and the preferred size of the textfield will probably end up being (0,0).

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout()); frame.getContentPane().add(txtInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);` is kind of pointless

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the combo box to the JTextField, add it to the frame by adding a panel to it.

Remove:

`frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(txtInput,BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Why would you set the layout to flow and add the textfield as borderlayout?

Add a main panel to the frame:

```
JPanel mainapnel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(mainpanel);
```

Add the JTextField to the panel:

```
mainpanel.add(txtInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

**EDIT**

Undo setting the layout for the JTextField, and isntead of adding the ComboBox to the JTextfield, add it to the panel:

```
mainpanel.add(cbInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```